# Redirect to same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, redirecttoaction

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC website and I am new to this. 
I have a controller with few actions. I want to use these actions through out my website.
For example

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(ViewModel model)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //code is here
    }
  return RedirectToAction(); // redirect to same view

}
```

I want to redirect to same view from where request is generated. I am not sure if this is possible or not ?

Comment: just return View() and it will be fine...

Comment: What you want is possible, however due to your question being vague it's hard to understand in what context you want it to work.  I'm assuming you want to keep your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry) but are you trying to reuse the Action Logic or the View Result?

Comment: @Erik Philips. I want to reuse both my view result and action logic

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I would create a Controller that looks like:

```
public MyController : Controller
{
  private ActionResult SharedMethod(SomeModel model)
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      //code is here
    }

    // viewname is required, otherwise the view name used will be
    // the original calling method (ie public1.cshtml, public2.cshtml)
    return this.View("SharedViewName");
  }

  public ActionResult Public1(SomeModel model)
  {
    return this.SharedMethod(model);
  }

  public ActionResult Public1(SomeModel model)
  {
    return this.SharedMethod(model);
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually I have a view which list all details of product from database. Clicking on a button opens a popup with a form in it.So I want to use this common action method to post comments and redirect user to same view (product page) with updated comments.